# Update variable dynamically based on variable from UI

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following array initialized in C# code. data1, data2, data3 as manually written in the code to assign it to 'row' as shown below.

```
string[] row = new string[] { type, data1, data2, data3, shares };
```

Instead of coding it manually, I want to dynamically assign. To ensure that happens, I take the value of a variable from the UI and assign it to a C# variable like this.

```
var change_data = "data1, data2"
```

So for example, I should be able to change the variable 'row' as follows:

```
 string[] row = new string[] { type, data1, data2, shares };
```

Now another example.

```
var change_data = "data1";
```

This should update row as follows too.

```
string[] row = new string[] { type, data1, shares };
```

Comment: Arrays in C# are fixed length, you might want to use a list instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @XanderLuciano-0 can you please tell me how to update a list based on this input value 'change_data

Comment: Would the value of `data_changed` always be delimited by a comma and space?

Comment: @DrewKennedy- Yes.

Comment: @DrewKennedy- var change_data = "data1"; is also a possibilty

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837588/change-c-sharp-variables-dynamically-based-on-input-variable-from-ui, which the author posted about an hour ago. The question was poorly received (as it should have been) and the author is attempting to bypass the voting system by deleting his previous attempt and posting it again.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think he's made *some* improvements in clarity, although they should have been edits to the OP, not a new question.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I would agree with "some", but the question is still too broad (for example, why does your answer not address the possible utility of using reflection? well, maybe that's to do with the fact that the OP hasn't yet even explained what `data1`, `data2`, etc. refer to). In any case, deleting posts in a blatant effort to avoid voting penalties is decidedly against Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Maybe this is going over my head, but there doesn't seem to be any need to use reflection to pull values from the UI and put them in a collection. This is pretty basic stuff, and reflection may very well go over the OP's head.

Comment: @Drew: it depends on where the variables are. And yes, reflection may well go over the OP's head, but we don't have any reason to believe that the OP is in a scenario where they are free to change the implementation to use a dictionary to store values instead of variables. A third alternative is a dictionary with delegate accessors, but that also may go over their head. Ultimately, going over the OP's head is always going to be a risk...especially when the question is too broad, allowing for a variety of possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, because of arrays having a fixed length, you'd be better served with using some sort of a collection. `Blorgbeard`'s answer uses a `Dictionary<K,V>` - another way is to use a `List<T>`.

What you can do is wrap a List inside a method to start your list off with your first value, insert your input values, and add the final value:

Assume the value of `input` below is `data1, data2`:

```
public static List<string> CreateRowData(string input) {
    var returnList = new List<string> { "type" };

    var inputs = input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());

    foreach (var item in inputs) {
        returnList.Add(item);
    }

    returnList.Add("shares");

    return returnList;
}
```

The above turns:

```
//type
//data1
//data2
//shares
```

Comment: This builds a row-list containing the strings "type", "data1", etc, rather than a row-list containing the values associated with the "type", "data1" variables. I don't *think* that's what OP was asking for, but he accepted this answer, so who knows?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah it was just a guess. I think I would prefer a Dictionary if the dataset was fairly large and a key-value structure is what the OP actually wants. I have no idea what the use case was.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use variables' names as strings like that. Instead, you could use a dictionary:

```
// setup
var fields = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
    {"data1", "data 1 value"},
    {"data2", "data 2 value"},
    {"data3", "data 3 value"},
};

// get data from UI
var change_data = "data1, data2";
var change_names = change_data.Split(',').Select(t=>t.Trim());

// or just this, if you can get it from your UI:
// var change_names = new [] {"data1", "data2"};

// build new row based on change_names
var row = new List<string>();
row.Add(type);
row.AddRange(change_names.Select(t=>fields[t]));
row.Add(shared);
```